# MER - Confusão temporal de cardinalidade

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, entidade-relacionamento

Estou com algumas dúvidas de aspecto temporal.

Exemplo:

```
[FUNCIONÁRIO]------<PERTENCE>------[DEPARTAMENTO]
```

Nesse caso é obvio: cada funcionário pertence a **um** departamento, e cada departamento tem N funcionários (seja no momento ou ao longo do tempo).

Até aí tudo bem, porém às vezes me perco em certas análises como uma que vi em uma apostila:

```
[PROFESSOR]1------<LECIONA>------N[ALUNO]
```

Cada professor leciona para N alunos, ***cada aluno é lecionado por 1 professor***.

Essa é a parte que me perco, a cada análise diferente percebo um aspecto temporal diferente. Logo, só me faria sentido essa frase caso cada aluno seja lecionado por 1 professor em um determinado período (***em uma aula***). Caso considerasse o aspecto temporal como indeterminado (***não mais em uma, mas em várias aulas***), então cada aluno é lecionado por N professores.

Lamento caso seja uma "dúvida" cretina, mas me perco demais em relação à isso.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Você está complicando porque está colocando uma variável que não existe. Esquece essa coisa de temporal. Pode até ser que em algum caso de modelagem essa variável seja relevante e tenha que considerar isto, mas tem que ter uma regra que determine claramente que que só pode ter um de cada vez.

Claro que eu não sei tudo sobre sua modelagem e até pode estar fazendo alguma coisa que faria sentido olhar para o tempo, mas em acho que está fazendo um modelo normal de uma escola. Então cada aluno está relacionado para vários professores. A não ser, talvez, que seja o início do ensino fundamental (mesmo assim não é garantido que tenha um só). O tempo neste caso é o período que o aluno está matriculado e não o tempo que o aluno está na sala de aula. Se o controle fosse pelo tempo da sala de aula aí poderia ser 1 para N (também poderia ter mais que um em algumas situações, mas não vou complicar porque isto é situação mais específica). No caso seria uma relação de N para M.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a confusão começa nesta análise:

```
[PROFESSOR]1------<LECIONA>------N[ALUNO]
```

Em associações 1 pra N, não existe uma tabela associativa entre eles. Você poderia expressar a relação da seguinte forma:

```
[PROFESSOR]1---------------------N[ALUNO]
```

Ou seja, `Aluno` referencia `Professor` através de uma chave estrangeira.

Sobre o aspecto temporal, tudo depende do objetivo que você tem. No exemplo anterior, sei que um `Aluno` "pertence" a um `Professor`, e que um `Professor` "possui" N `Aluno`s. No mundo real, este conceito é um pouco absurdo, mas para a modelagem relacional, faz todo o sentido, pois é a maneira genérica de expressar as relações.

Agora, se o `Aluno` "possui" não `Professor`es, mas `Aula`s ministradas por `Professores`, observe que o diagrama volta a ser associativo:

```
[PROFESSOR]N------<AULA>------N[ALUNO]
```

Observe também que essa expressão "por função" (ou seja, ter uma "entidade" chamada "leciona") é bastante problemática. As funções não são entidades: são descrições da relação entre as entidades. Repare que faria muito mais sentido expressar a relação entre `Aula`s, `Aluno`s e `Professor`es da seguinte forma:

```
            LECIONA       PARTICIPA DE
[PROFESSOR]N--------<AULA>------------N[ALUNO]
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema possivelmente esteja dividido ou possa ser interpretado de 2 formas ou partes.

## Primeira parte

Os livros geralmente não colocam a cardinalidade mínima, somente a máxima o que pode deixar o exemplo um pouco confuso.

Imagine nesse caso que a cardinalidade seja PROFESSOR (0,1) leciona ALUNO (0,N) veja que a tradução disso seria:

> Um aluno qualquer pode ter aulas ou não com determinado professor, e um professor pode ou não da aulas, perceba que a cardinalidade mínima nas duas entidades, passa um grau de independência entre elas, ou seja, **professor** existe independentemente de aluno assim como **aluno** existe independentemente do professor.

## Segunda Parte

Acredito também que esse exemplo está incompleto, perceba que falta uma entidade no meio de **professor** e **aluno**, e ela se chama **disciplina**.

Todo professor leciona em uma disciplina para os alunos.

A dificuldade maior nesse exemplo é entender que existe essa entidade oculta, pois estamos falando de um exemplo de relacionamento ternário, caso não saiba o que é um relacionamento ternário sugiro dar uma pesquisada, é um pouco difícil de compreender de primeira.

Acompanhe no desenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Notação MER de um Ternário**

Veja que as 3 entidades existem independentemente uma das outras, mas tente tirar uma delas e verás que perde o sentido, na prática esse ternário será desmembrado em 3 relacionamentos do tipo 1:M e dará origem a uma tabela nova servindo de apoio para as três.

Essa nova entidade guardará as chaves estrangeiras das demais como chave primária em si mesma.

## Tentando facilitar o entendimento

Eu costumo encaixar um ternário em uma frase com sujeito e predicado, por exemplo:

O professor leciona disciplinas para os alunos

Geralmente os substantivos são entidades e os verbos são os relacionamentos.

Substativos: O professor, A Disciplina, O aluno.

Verbo: Lecionar.

> Perceba também que o verbo lecionar é transitivo direto e indireto ou seja quem leciona, leciona algo (disciplina) para alguém (aluno)